# Email send in django

Tags: django, email

I am trying to send the email from django web app. I used following

```
 from django.core.mail import send_mail
 send_mail('test email', 'hello world', 'your@email.com', ['aman.kumar@thoughts2binary.com'])
```

my setting is

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'support@indianangelnetwork.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@indianangelnetwork.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
```

i am always getiing the mail from "support@indianangelnetwork.com". Although i am passing the send_from value.

Comment: Is this the same if you make an actual [`EmailMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) object?, the from email is usually only ever used if it is omitted

Comment: yaa in that case i am getting same

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you did not specify the password for your@email.com.
As a result Django falls back to the default settings.

[See documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/)

Comment: You may want to provide a quote from the documentation that states where this is the case and how to solve this problem. (It's most likely the correct answer)

Comment: i have already make the connection using 'support@indianangelnetwork.com' this email. I just want to send_from will other

Comment: @AmanKUmar does your@email.com and 'support@indianangelnetwork.com' have the same password?If not you should specify the password explicitly in code.